# include php function to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web

in test.php file

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="java_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

in java_script.js

```
function myFunction() {
    var user_name = 'Hellow World';
    document.getElementById("myText").value = user_name;
}
```

How to use function or variable from php_test.php

in php_test.php

```
  <?php
      $phpVar = 'Hello World';
      echo $phpVar;
  ?>
```

Thank you everyone 
i'm not good in English, You can correct me :)

Comment: How would you like to use the PHP variable?

Comment: you need to make ajax request to get the values/arrays from php to js and vise versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**clabe45**'s answer is good, but I thought I'd add some more information in my own words.

**PHP** is a server-side language. It's run by the server. It can be used for whatever you want, but it's often used to generate **HTML** and sometimes **Javascript**. The HTML and Javascript is then sent to the browser. The browser parses (reads) the HTML and displays it in the browser, and it runs the Javascript. The HTML is what you see on the page (text, images, borders, etc.). The Javascript is used to add interactivity to the page (drop-down menus, animations, popup boxes, etc.).

Since PHP runs on the server and Javascript runs in the browser (on the client), Javascript can't access variables that are in the PHP code. The Javascript doesn't know anything about the PHP, and vice versa.

The way Javascript normally talks to PHP is through **AJAX**. The Javascript code can send an AJAX request to the server, and the PHP code on the server can respond to that request. clabe45's answer has some more details about AJAX (and you should definitely check out [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and google some tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a little unclear, but I will do my best.

#### PHP

PHP stands for

> PHP: Hypertext *Preprocessor*

It has *preprocessor* in its name because it only runs on the *server*, **before** it is sent to the HTML page for parsing (which is done by the browser).

#### JavaScript

Javascript runs **after** the HTML page has been received by the browser. Thus, one could assume that he/she couldn't run PHP from javascript, because PHP runs *before* javascript. However, AJAX is a solution to this dilemma; it stands for

> asynchronous JavaScript and XML

#### AJAX

AJAX requests can be sent *to the server*, *from javascript*, *during the browsing session*. In other words, the PHP code can be re-run during the browsing session, and its output can be sent straight to javascript.
[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has some very easy-to-use methods for using AJAX in your javascript code. You need to provide the `url` to the PHP program to be run and an object of key/value `settings`.

I hoped this helped.

Comment: Thank you krub (ขอบคุณครับ)